# The inverse of $T$ with $Tx(t)=t\int_0^tx(s)ds$ is not bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem:
[image]
[image]

I already proved that $T$ is a bounded linear operator, and that it is not surjective.
Now, my guess is that I can use the Closed Graph Theorem, but I do not see why. Any hints?

Comment: Just ask yourself where to what does $T^{-1}$ map the functions $t^{n+1}$.

Comment: To something like $t^{n-1}$... but what then?

Comment: You do not need to use any hard result at all, @Simoes Just check using the definition that the operator $T^{-1}$ is unbounded. As hinted, all $\{ t^n\}$ has norm one, but the norm of $T^{-1}(t^n)$ goes to infinity.

Comment: This is your homework, so do some work. "Something like $t^{n-1}$" is not  true. Do some calculations.

Comment: @JohnMa Ok, thanks. I think I got it: $t\int_0^ts^{n-1}ds=\frac{t^{n+1}}{n}$. So $T^{-1}(x\text{ such that }x(t)=t^{n+1})(t)=nt^{n-1}$. So $$\parallel T^{-1}(t^{n+1}) \parallel=\text{max}_{t\in[0,1]}(nt^{n-1})=n\cdot 1$$
 ($\parallel t^{n+1}) \parallel=1$). Now, whatever $C$ I take, I can take $n$ bigger than $C$.